# unmount state update in useEffect() cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, axios

To get data from API I call a http request. Sometimes I warned with a error that tell me I am trying to update state which unmounted. To solve that, I use clean up function in useEffect() hook like this:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const token = source.token;

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await ProductService.getProducts(token);
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message, error.response.status);
      }
    };

    fetchProducts();

    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
```

and my service file like this:

```
const ProductService = {
  getProducts: async function (token) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(myURL, {
        cancelToken: token

      });
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
};
```

Have I done anything wrong or unnecessary thing in this case or can I update this code block ??
Please help me.

Comment: I don't see any enqueued state updates in your example code snippets. Is this accurate code giving you issue?

Comment: Though my useEffect has empty dependency, so that it ran only first time when the page is rendered. Suppose, from navigation menu I go to my product page and before we get product data we click on another page. In this case, I saw unmount state update.

Comment: What state is being updated? I get what you are saying, but we can't help fix what we can't see.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I edited my question. Please help me.

Comment: Are you experiencing any particular problem with this code? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, so you're in the twilight zone between the asynchronous request succeeding, so the cancel token won't work, and the enqueued state update.

From here you've a couple options.

1. Ignore since this is only a warning. You've already tried cancelling in-flight network requests, or unsubscribed from subscriptions, etc... so at this point it's only a warning.
2. Use the old `isMounted` hack.

Using the `isMounted` hack uses a mutable reference in the `useEffect` hook that will always be synchronously updated when unmounting, and can be a final check before enqueueing the state update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
  const token = source.token;

  let isMounted = true;

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await ProductService.getProducts(token);
      isMounted && setProducts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message, error.response.status);
    }
  };

  fetchProducts();

  return () => {
    isMounted = false;
    source.cancel();
  };
}, []);
```

I call this a hack as it's *really* only a way to skirt/stifle the warning. React state updates to unmounted components are ignored anyway.

Comment: I loved that. Thanks. By the way, is it really necessary what I have done that using `async await` in both service file and useEffect() hook?

Comment: @Nasir `getData` is declared `async` so it implicitly returns a Promise. Consuming code can either also be declared `async` and `await` the resolved/rejected Promise, or remain synchronous and chain from the returned Promise.